# Why did Bald Rob want to cut Earl's truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mule

In *The Mule* (2018), Earl drives his truck inside the garage of a tire shop and meets some men:

> Andres: Where do you want us to **cut the compartment**, huh? Under the
>   seat?
>
> Earl: Do what to the compartment?
>
> Andres: **Cut up your truck**.

Why did Bald Rob want to cut Earl's truck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose they wanted to cut the truck in order to create a secret compartment to hide the drugs in.
It is a common method to hide and move drugs.
See this [story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSq74VNl17c) as an example